# Why are results of evaluation different for do form standalone vs in function in clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm experiencing unexpected evaluation of the identical `(do ...)` form when evaluated in a function vs being evaluated in REPL standalone. Here's the first example:

```
;Example1
(defn example [req] 
  (do
    (println (-> req :body :text))
    (create-message! (-> req :body :text))
    (println (map :text (get-messages)))
    )
  )
(example {:body {:text "text1"}})
```

Output of the println will be the following for example1:

```
text1
()
```

Here's the 2nd example:

```
;Example2
(def req {:body {:text "text1"}})
(do
  (println (-> req :body :text))
  (create-message! (-> req :body :text))
  (println (map :text (get-messages)))
)
```

Output here is:

```
text1
(text1)
```

Function create-message! prepends a message to an atom list. Function get-messages returns the atom list.

In the 1st example it seems that result of the 2nd println is an empty list, instead of the expected one-element list containing "text1". The atom list does get updated as expected in both examples. It seems as if get-messages get evaluated before create-message! in 1st example (or something else unexpected is happening).

What is happening here and why?

**EDIT**

Here's the code for create-message and get-messages

```
(defn get-messages
  ([] (get-messages 10))
  ([length] (get-messages length (jt/instant)))
  ([length before] (take length (filter #(jt/before? (:timestamp %) before) @domain/messages)))
  )


(defn create-message!
  [text]
  (swap! domain/messages #(cons (domain/->Message (jt/instant) text) %))
  )
```

Here's the definition of the messages atom in domain namespace:

```
(ns chatovic.domain)
(defrecord Message [timestamp text])
(def messages (atom []))
```

Comment: Hi! Could you share your `create-message!` function? Are you sure you use atoms and not agents?

Comment: Hi - added the code that mutates / fetches data in the atom list.

Comment: I don't have an answer right now but I would check if it is not time sensitive - it seems you use some filtering based on the message time.

Comment: Hmm.. it happens even with modified code (see latest edit) where filtering doesn't happen

Comment: Actually I was wrong - it was the timing issue! I'll revert the edit you can post the answer and I'll accept it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code uses `(jt/instant)` to filter messages returned from your atom and this might lead to different results between invocations due to time sensitivity.